# Is the set of Turing Machines decidable in ZFC non-recursive?

Tags: set-theory, computability, turing-machines

Let S be the set of all the TMs which halting is decidable in ZFC (for each TM in S, we can find one algorithm in ZFC that determines whether the machine halts or not). Is S recursive? Is there one algorithm that can enumerate both the stopping and non-stopping machines of S?

For example, would the set of Diophantine equations still be non-computable if we removed those instances that are independent of ZFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assume $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound.*

For each sentence $\varphi$ in the language of set theory, consider the machine $T_\varphi$ which - regardless of input - searches for a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof or disproof of $\varphi$ and halts iff it finds one. Then $T_\varphi$ halts iff $\varphi$ is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-decidable, and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves this.

Since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete, if $T_\varphi$ halts (on input $0$, say) then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that $T_\varphi$ halts. What if $T_\varphi$ doesn't halt? Well, then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't prove that $T_\varphi$ *does* halt by the soundness assumption above, and by the last four words of the previous paragraph + Godel's second incompleteness theorem $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't prove that $T_\varphi$ *doesn't* halt either (otherwise $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would prove that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent).

So the halting status of $T_\varphi$ is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-decidable iff $\mathsf{ZFC}$ decides $\varphi$. But it's a standard exercise that the set of $\mathsf{ZFC}$-decidable sentences isn't computable, since otherwise we could build a computable consistent complete extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ contradicting the first incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Does the fact that the set of ZFC-decidable sentences is not computable also implies that  the set of Diophantine equations that are decidable in ZFC is not computable? I assume this must be right because of the equivalence between Turing Machines and Diophantine equations, but I would like to confirm.

Comment: @CharbelBejjani Yes, that's correct.

Comment: One last question @Noah : does the fact that the list of theorems proved by ZFC is r.e. but not recursive implies that there is no algorithm to decide if an arbitrary Turing Machine expressible in ZFC and decidable by ZFC, halts or not? I read somewhere that there always is an algorithm that decides the behavior of all Turing Machines that are decidable by a formal system, but I can't seem to reconcile this with the fact the the list of theorems proved in a formal system is non-recursive. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: @CharbelBejjani Yes, we can brute-force-search through $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proofs and so computably enumerate the set of machines which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves halt on input $0$ (say). Using the same logic we can computably enumerate the set of machines which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves *don't* halt on input $0$ (say). However, this doesn't contradict the fact that the set of theorems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is non-computable. What's going on here is the distinction between computable and computably enumerable: the set of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ theorems *is* computably enumerable.

Comment: So for any sufficiently complex formal system, there always is one algorithm that can solve _all_ Diophantine equations (including the ones that don't have solutions) that are decidable by the system right?

Comment: @CharbelBejjani If by "solve" you mean "determine whether they are solvable," yes. However, note that the set of such equations isn't computable.

Comment: I mean solve "determine whether any ZFC-decidable equations have solutions or not, and if they do, find the solutions also". Is there such an algorithm? For example, I would give it an arbitrary Diophantine equation that can be solved in ZFC, and it will _always_ be able to solve it? (find the solutions or determine that there is no solutions)